# Bake textures from hair converted to mesh

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, workflow, texture-baking, hair

I am wanting to create textures based on a hair particle system.

The answer to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66658/bake-hair-particle-system-to-textured-low-poly-mesh) says

> There are 2 techniques. One giving the best results but being rather complicated and very computationally expensive (involving converting the hair to mesh, UV mapping the hair strands in a particular way and baking particle color in another complicate way and then baking the whole thing)

That's all they say about the first option, they then go on to explain a second option which I tried, but was not happy with the result. I would also like to bake a normal map, which is not possible using that technique.

What are the details of the first technique?